# How to get bundler to always pull latest commit from private gem repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

Is this possible force bunlder to always get the latest commit? Something like:

`gem "gemname", :git => "git@bitbucket.org:/username/gemname.git", ref: :force-latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
bundle update gemname
```

The `bundle update` command uses the latest available version of the named gem that is compatible with the specification in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use `master` branch to get latest `commit`

lets for `rails`

```
gem "rails", github: "rails/rails",  branch: "master"
```